# Resetting the appearance of UIBarButtonItems and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Let us say I used some code to change the `appearance` property of the `UINavigationBar` including the `UIBarButtonItems` in my app. Is there any simple way to reset the appearance for some specific views to the default iOS style?

Comment: You could `tag` each view to access later.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options I can think of.

1. Save the initial state in variables (background, font etc) to use
   later during the reset.
2. Destroy and recreate the view. If this is done during a transition
   (page switch etc) it may not be noticeable to the user.
3. Keep the original view hidden behind the new view and destroy the
   new view when you want to reset it. (This may be memory expensive.)

I think your best bet may be to create a custom object (extend the original NavBar etc), save its original appearance variables (color, font etc) and add a reset option to be called by the controller.

Comment: Nice one. I will try it.